# If a circuit from a voltage source has a potentiometer to ground, does voltage increase or decrease when resistance does?

Tags: voltage, resistance, potentiometer

Below is a [CRT circuit](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/642880104070119426/842462865034313798/unknown.png?width=1472&height=1332) I am trying to fix, specifically the HV circuit.

In the bottom right corner, a reference voltage comes from the flyback and makes it's way to U701 on the HV. IN pin. My question deals with potentiometer VR722 (beside R722), going to ground.

[image]

As the resistance increases, what happens to the voltage? Does it increase as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R722 and VR722 appear to be the lower elements of a potential divider consisting of the undesignated resistor chain (1) on the right of the transformer. Lowering the resistance of VR722 will **reduce** the voltage at (2). (Think of the extreme conditions: if you reduce R722/VR722 to zero the output would be 0 V; if you open-circuit VR722 - making it infinite resistance - you will get Hv volts out.)

[image]

Be aware though that usually reducing the feedback voltage like this will **increase** the output voltage as the regulator will increase the output in an effort to get the feedback voltage up to its internal reference voltage value.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation! It also explains the symptoms I had: Turning the pot to the left of the original factory position (increase resistance) had no effect on the voltage change before the protection circuit tripped. I was just increasing voltage.

Talk about bad physical design since the other pot beside it works in the other direction.